# What does this mean exactly 今天的书。

Tags: translation

is this an insult my boyfriend said this. I have many other things I have questions on im from Texas him Jiangsu.

Comment: No. Your bf needs to give more context.

Comment: It means "the book of today" directly. Maybe someone has some kind of daily book to read?

Comment: Maybe talk to the bf directly? Otherwise, the relationship is not going anywhere!

Answer (score 2):

It means exactly "today's book".

I highly recommend talking to your boyfriend about any questions, he will be able to answer and we cannot, only you two have real life context to match the language (and anything not).

Answer (score 0):

"is this an insult my boyfriend said this"?

If 今天的书, (The book of the day), is used in a human / romantic relationship, yes, my view is it is an insult. It means its popularity, relevance lasts no longer than a day.

It's something like "The flavor of the month", "Today's news"

A compliment would be 千年之书, (Book of the Millennium)